Shortcut to open On-Screen Touchpad
I'm trying to launch the On-Screen touchpad build into windows10/11
I haven't had any luck locating a .exe which launches the program.
So far I have only found how to launch it from the taskbar


Just because something has a visual element does not mean it exits as an executable that can be initialized discretely. In other words, what proof do you have that the OS Touchpad has an executable that you can run? Rather than trying to find an .exe, perhaps consider HOW you'd like to be able to start it, and we can find alternative ways to do this without needing to track down an .exe that might not actually exist. In other words, what are you trying to do that you think finding the .exe will help you accomplish?

To invoke onscreen keyboard, %windir%\system32\osk.exe works. Perhaps use Task Manager to see what app runs when you start the on-screen touchpad.

@music2myear that is a fair point. For some background I'm developing a SCADA application with Ignition which runs in a chromium web browser, additionally it has python scripting. I've had feedback from the users that when using the application on a tablet having fine pointer control would be beneficial. So I figured this would suit well if I could launch it from our application.

@DrMoishePippik Yes I had found that which made me think that surely there is something similar for the on-screen touch pad. I tried digging through Task manager with little luck.

The on screen touchpad has to be always "running" when you've enabled the item in the taskbar, because it shows and hides instantly, with no loading delay. This makes me think it is a dll integrated called by Explorer or something like that, rather than a discrete exe.
